# How can I use for loop (or something which has indent) inside eval in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

What I want to implement is:

If passed argment array's length is three, execute self-defined function (in this case `regex_rep`) with the array as argments.

```
regex_rep(args[1], args[2], args[3])
```

In case of the length is four, the array must be expanded as argments like following.

```
regex_rep(args[1], args[2], args[3], args[4])
```

The idea I came up with to implement this is using eval. I'm using Bash, In Bash, you can use eval like this:

```
eval "regex_rep\($( for i in ${args[@]}; do echo "args[i], " ; done | sed -Ee 's/, $//g' )\)"
```

So I tried following one, but I got an error `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`.

```
eval("""
for i in ["some","thing"]:
  print(i)
""")
```

My question is: How can I use for loop (or something which has indent) inside eval? and additionally if you have better idea to implement above one let me know. Thanks.

Comment: `eval` evaluates expressions. You're looking for `exec`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`eval` only evaluates expressions, a for-loop is a block of code that could be `exec`uted.

However, from what I can tell from your question, what you really want is argument expansion:

```
regex_rep(*args)
```

This fills in the arguments from the `args` list.

Comment: And you can use `**kwargs` if you use a dict and want to send it as keyword arguments.